# Use the toString() method to print a numbered list of String Array objects

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

This is what I am trying to output:

```
Choose an option :

(1) Water

(2) Soda pop

(3) Beer

?-> Enter an option number :
```

This is my code:

```
public class Menu 
{   

    private String[] optionList;

    private String openingMessage;

    private String topPrompt;

    private String closingMessage;

    private String bottomPrompt;


    public Menu(String[] options)
    {
        optionList = options;
        openingMessage = "";
        topPrompt = "Choose an option:";
        closingMessage = "";
        bottomPrompt = "Enter an option number:";
    }

    public Menu()
    {
        optionList = null;
        openingMessage = "";
        topPrompt = "";
        closingMessage = "";
        bottomPrompt = "";
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(String[] options)
    {
        if (options == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int length(String[] options)
    {
        return options.length;
    }

    public String toString()
    {       
        return (topPrompt + "\n" + "?->" + " " + bottomPrompt);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String[] drink_options = {"Water", "Soda pop", "Beer"};

        Menu drinkMenu = new Menu(drink_options);

        System.out.println(drinkMenu);
        //System.out.println(drinkMenu.isEmpty(drink_options));
        //System.out.println(drinkMenu.length(drink_options));
    }
```

What will I have to do in the `toString()` method in order for the numbers in brackets to appear before each listing of the `String` array elements? I am thinking I could use the `length()` method to obtain the number n of elements inside the array and use a for loop to add the numbers in front.

Please let me know your insights.

Thank you!

Comment: "What will I have to do in the toString() method..." some for-loop, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: "I am thinking I could use the length() method to obtain the number n of elements inside the array and use a for loop to add the numbers in front." Yes, that will definitely work.

Comment: Unsolicited advice: `isEmpty()` should probably not take any arguments. Instead, it should use the member variable to check if the menu is empty.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice
I followed your suggestion and made isEmpty() argument-less. Would it be possible to call the isEmpty() method inside of the length() method?

Comment: @glowstarraw Yes, it is certainly legal to do that. What purpose do you have to do so?

Comment: I am uncertain about your definition of "empty". Note that it is possible to create an array with 0 elements. You can also make it impossible for `optionList` to every be `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return options == null || options.length == 0
}

public int length()
{
    return isEmpty() ? 0 : options.length;
}

public String toString()
{       
    String result = topPrompt + "\n";
    for (i=0; i<lenth(); i++) {
         result += "(" + (i+1)+ ") " + options[i]; 
    }
    result  += "?->" + " " + bottomPrompt);
    return result;
}
```